# remove blank line preceding form feed in text file

Tags: regex, awk

I have a question:
is it possible, using regular expressions, remove, in a text file, the blank records preceding the form feed character ?
Thanks

Comment: Most likely. You should post some example data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since it might be hard to produce sample data with form feed (`\f` or `\L`, depending on the software) in it, I'll create the test case. Something like this should work:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "FIRST\n\n\n\n\f\nLAST"}' > foo
$ less foo
FIRST



^L
LAST
$ awk -v RS="asdad" 'gsub(/\n+\f/,"\n\f")' foo > bar
$ less bar
FIRST
^L
LAST
```

ie. change the `RS` to something nonexistent and use `sub`.

**Edit**: Changed `sub` to `gsub`, should've been in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, it work with the first /f
and if there are several /f in the text file

Comment: there is a similar solution ?

Comment: I don't understand. Ah, ok, got it. Use `gsub` instead of `sub`.